# Dynamic Program to find well formed set in a rooted tree

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, dynamic-programming, trees

> You are given a rooted tree $T=(V,E)$ with $n$ nodes and the root $r$. Each node $u\in V$ has an integer label $l(u)$. Suppose $S⊆V$ then $S$ is well-formed if for every $u,v\in S$ if $u$ is an ancestor or the parent of $v$ then $l(u)\le l(v)$. Let $wf(T)$ be the maximum size of any well-formed set in $T$. How can we construct a dynamic program to compute $wf(T)$.

Can we have bottom up aproach? or a modified DFS ?

It'd be helpful if one could give me a hint of how to approach the problem ?

**Possible Strategy**

Create a table to store the maxium size of well-formed subsets for each node $u$. We can initialize the value for each node in the table as $1$ considering only the  node $u$ itself. Start from the bottom leaves to the top root. For each node, consider its parents and compare the integer number of it and its parent node and update the parent node's score in the table. Iterate it till we reach the root node. The maximum size of the well-formed set is the maximum of the table values.

Comment: Try computing for each subtree $T'$ and label $\ell$ the maximum size of a well-formed subset of $T'$ in which all label values are at least $\ell$.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all material originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Please follow the guidance in https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info, then [edit] your question to show your progress.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your remarks. I tried to update the post with my attempt.